# Error when opening the executable of a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, inno-setup, phpdesktop

I converted a Laravel project into PC Software (setup.exe) with live Database MySQL, using PHP Desktop chrome and Inno Setup but when opening the executable an error was generated:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Data Management App\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 16

What is the reason for that error please and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please check your `laravel` and `php` version first

Comment: I am abit ignorant here, I confess, but this doesn't sound like a Inno Setup issue IMHO.